# why am i getting There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name loginAction?

Tags: java, eclipse, spring, struts2, weblogic

I got an Struts 2 + Hibernate + Spring Eclipse web application.

It was originally build to run with Tomcat 7.0, but when I try to migrate it to WeblLogic 12c I get the exception:"There is no Action mapped for namespace / and action name loginAction."

The weird thing is that if I launch the application from eclipse to run on Weblogic it works fine, but if I export the war and deploy it manually I get the previous error mentioned.
In my struts.xml I have a couple of configuration, but most of the struts configurations are annotations.

Here is my struts.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE struts PUBLIC
    "-//Apache Software Foundation//DTD Struts Configuration 2.0//EN"
    "http://struts.apa che.org/dtds/struts-2.0.dtd">
<struts>
    <constant name="struts.action.excludePattern" value="/rest/.*?" />
    <constant name="struts.devMode" value="false" />
    <constant name="struts.multipart.maxSize" value="104857600" />
    <package name="mi-paquete" extends="struts-default">
        <result-types>
            <result-type name="tiles"
                class="org.apache.struts2.views.tiles.TilesResult" />
        </result-types>
        <interceptors>
            <interceptor name="LoginInterceptor"
                class="com.proximate.www.pushmate.interceptors.LoginInterceptor" />
            <interceptor-stack name="loginStack">
                <interceptor-ref name="LoginInterceptor" />
                <interceptor-ref name="defaultStack" />
            </interceptor-stack>
        </interceptors>
        <default-interceptor-ref name="loginStack" />
        <global-results>
            <result name="loginAction">/jsp/template/loginLayout.jsp</result>
            <result name="errorAction">/jsp/error/error.jsp</result>
        </global-results>
        <action name="olvidoContrasenia"
            class="com.proximate.www.pushmate.action.OlvidoContraseniaAction">
            <result name="formResult">/jsp/template/olvidoContrasenaLayout.jsp</result>
        </action>
    </package>
</struts>
```

Here is an excerpt of my login action:

```
@ParentPackage("mi-paquete")
@Action(value="loginAction")
@InterceptorRefs({
    @InterceptorRef(value="defaultStack", params = {"excludeMethods","validaUsuario"})
})
@Results({
    @Result(name="success", location="/jsp/template/loginLayout.jsp"),
    @Result(name=ActionsConstants.ERROR, type="tiles", location=ActionsConstants.URL_ERROR),
    @Result(name = "welcome", type = "redirectAction", location = "welcomeAction.action"),
    @Result(name = "registroUsuario", location = "/jsp/template/concluyeRegistroLayout.jsp"),
})
public class LoginAction extends ActionSupport implements SessionAware, ServletRequestAware {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1218879876500264583L;
    private static final Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(LoginAction.class.getName());
    private Login loginObj;
    private static String URLAplication = null;
    private static String URLReportes = null;

    @Autowired
    private IUsuarioService usuarioService;

    @Autowired
    private IMenuDAO menuUsuarioDAO;

    @Autowired
    private ILogDAO logDAO;

    Map<String, Object> session;
    HttpServletRequest request;

    @Override
    public String execute() throws Exception {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return validaUsuario();
    }
}
```

Does anyone knows why are the struts2 annotations failing????
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added the next 2 lines in my struts.xml in order to fix the problem:

```
<constant name="struts.convention.action.includeJars" value=".*?\.jar(!/|/)?" />
<constant name="struts.convention.action.fileProtocols" value="jar,zip" />
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify namespace. Have you tried like:

```
@Action(value="/loginAction")
```